# Braintree: What is paymentMethodToken required in creating subscriptions?

Tags: braintree

https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/guides/recurring-billing/create

```
    result = Braintree_Subscription::create(array(
    'paymentMethodToken' => 'the_token',
    'planId' => 'silver_plan'
    ));
```

Is it a random generated string in my code? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paymentMethodToken is a unique identifier for the customer's credit card to use.  After you create a Customer with a stored payment method you can use the returned token to subscribe a user to a plan.  This article explains it well:

https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/guides/recurring-billing/overview

Comment: If user's payment method is paypal, what is the token?